# Корректно ли писать 0px в CSS?

Tags: html, css

Вопрос в заголовке уже полностью сформулирован, мне остаётся только пояснить, зачем это нужно. Удобно это в основном при настройке позиционирования, когда вы подбираете координаты. Если вы в процессе подбора меняете значение с нулевого на ненулевое, а потом опять на нулевое, то надоест то дописывать, то стирать `px`.

Comment: Конечно корректно. Более того, иногда необходимо…

Comment: @AlexeyTen, когда может быть необходимо указывать единицы измерения для значения 0?

Comment: @Grundy в шоркате для flex https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex `flex: 0` → `flex-grow=0`, `flex: 0px` → `flex-basis=0px`. Надо признать, что я знаю только этот случай. Но не исключаю, что может быть ещё где-то в аналогичной ситуации.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, забавно :-)

Comment: @Grundy, ещё с `calc()` поведение странное немного, хотя может и нет: https://jsfiddle.net/4gmcbzka/ . Я там в комментариях пометил ...

Comment: @RomanGrinyov, с `calc` все по [спецификации](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values/#calc-syntax): там получается что внутри `calc` это еще не `length` поэтому у `0` нельзя опускать размерность. И инструменты разработчика также показывают, что правило некорректное в случае отсутствия размерности

Comment: @RomanGrinyov, вернее даже вот так: _If one side is a <number> and the other is an <integer>, resolve to <number>._, то есть на выходе calc получается число _100_, а это невалидное значение для свойства margin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как сказано в [спецификации](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values/#lengths):

> for zero lengths the unit identifier is optional

---

> Для нулевых значений указание единиц измерения - опционально

Таким образом нет никакой разницы указывать ли для значения `0` единицы измерения или нет.

К тому же, как ни странно: 0px === 0em === 0%